# What requirements (if any) of being a Hindu apply to Sannyasis?

Tags: sannyasa

I believe they are required to break their connections with their family when they take Sannyasa - are they required to carry out any duties / obligations of being Hindu?

Comment: What there left when they have renounced all.. Including vedic rites

Comment: Who can be Sannyasis? Or Who are qualified and who are not? Is this the Q?

Comment: The usual mongoose-bite.  The questions are so clearly non-duplicate.